# Heroku Run Migrations Before Deploying Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, migration

I would like to run migrations *before* deploying code to my Heroku instance. This is because the code I write is backwards compatible with my database and if the migrations take a long time I don't want to push the code first, put the app in maintence mode until the migrations are done and then take the app out of maintenence mode.

If such a solution exists or something that would solve my problem I would like to know about it. Currently I have a separate box with all the code (and migrations) that accepts the push first then runs the migrations then deploys the code to Heroku.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Why not simply push your migrations to Heroku, do your db:migrate, then push the rest?

Comment: That might work. Just a little extra git fu.

Comment: Pushing a single folder in git will require rebase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I think your current solution is the only logical one. What you want to actually do is to push the database and the code at the same time, but not the whole database, only the schema. I think that can only be done like you did, and there is no need to do it in another way, because this is exactly what you wanted -- that something handles your push to Heroku, runs the database migrations, and pushes everything together.

Answer (score -3):

you could `heroku db:pull` run your migrations on your local, then `heroku db:push` and then deploy.

Comment: I need to only push/pull the schema not data.

Comment: This would push any local data from the dev machine to the remote database as well, and would take a long time for big databases.